# Using AES encryption in .NET - CryptographicException saying the padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: .net, cryptography, aes

I wrote some AES encryption code in C# and I am having trouble getting it to encrypt and decrypt properly. If I enter "test" as the passphrase and "This data must be kept secret from everyone!" I receive the following exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   ...
```

And if I enter something less than 16 characters I get no output.

I believe I need some special handling in the encryption since AES is a block cipher, but I'm not sure exactly what that is, and I wasn't able to find any examples on the web showing how. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class DatabaseCrypto
{
    public static EncryptedData Encrypt(string password, string data)
    {
        return DatabaseCrypto.Transform(true, password, data, null, null) as EncryptedData;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string password, EncryptedData data)
    {
        return DatabaseCrypto.Transform(false, password, data.DataString, data.SaltString, data.MACString) as string;
    }

    private static object Transform(bool encrypt, string password, string data, string saltString, string macString)
    {
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            int key_len = aes.KeySize / 8;
            int iv_len = aes.BlockSize / 8;
            const int salt_size = 8;
            const int iterations = 8192;

            byte[] salt = encrypt ? new byte[salt_size] : Convert.FromBase64String(saltString);
            if (encrypt)
            {
                new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt);
            }

            byte[] bc_key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("BLK" + password, salt, iterations).GetBytes(key_len);
            byte[] iv = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("IV" + password, salt, iterations).GetBytes(iv_len);
            byte[] mac_key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MAC" + password, salt, iterations).GetBytes(16);

            aes.Key = bc_key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            byte[] rawData = encrypt ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data) : Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            using (ICryptoTransform transform = encrypt ? aes.CreateEncryptor() : aes.CreateDecryptor())
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = encrypt ? new MemoryStream() : new MemoryStream(rawData))
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, encrypt ? CryptoStreamMode.Write : CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                if (encrypt)
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);

                    return new EncryptedData(salt, mac_key, memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] originalData = new byte[rawData.Length];
                    int count = cryptoStream.Read(originalData, 0, originalData.Length);

                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalData, 0, count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class EncryptedData
{
    public EncryptedData()
    {
    }

    public EncryptedData(byte[] salt, byte[] mac, byte[] data)
    {
        this.Salt = salt;
        this.MAC = mac;
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public EncryptedData(string salt, string mac, string data)
    {
        this.SaltString = salt;
        this.MACString = mac;
        this.DataString = data;
    }

    public byte[] Salt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string SaltString
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBase64String(this.Salt); }
        set { this.Salt = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
    }

    public byte[] MAC
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MACString
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBase64String(this.MAC); }
        set { this.MAC = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DataString
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBase64String(this.Data); }
        set { this.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
    }
}

    static void ReadTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("aes.cs.txt"))
        {
            EncryptedData enc = new EncryptedData();
            enc.SaltString = reader.ReadLine();
            enc.MACString = reader.ReadLine();
            enc.DataString = reader.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("The decrypted data was: " + DatabaseCrypto.Decrypt(password, enc));
        }
    }

    static void WriteTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter data: ");
        string data = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        EncryptedData enc = DatabaseCrypto.Encrypt(password, data);

        using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("aes.cs.txt"))
        {
            stream.WriteLine(enc.SaltString);
            stream.WriteLine(enc.MACString);
            stream.WriteLine(enc.DataString);

            Console.WriteLine("The encrypted data was: " + enc.DataString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using a block cipher like AES in a mode that requires padding, like CBC, you must be aware that the output will always be a multiple of the block size. To accomplish this, padding modes like PKCS7 will add some bytes to the cipher *at the end of the encryption process*. But you have to let the encryptor know when the end occurs. To do so, all you have to do is insert the statement

```
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

after

```
cryptoStream.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
```

PS:

Perhaps it is just for debugging, but your salt generation method generates the exact same salt every time.

Comment: Wow, simple as that, eh? I thought it might have been something to do with FlushFinalBlock but I wasn't sure. I think I added it before but maybe I was just entering the wrong password. I should generate some random unit tests. :) Also I know the salt is the same - I wasn't sure how to generate a random one yet but I found `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` after writing that code. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: So many examples in msdn and stackoverflow are not so healthy, and this answer saved my day. FlushFinalBlock(). Wow.

Comment: Was wrapping the CryptoStream in a StreamWriter... `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();` needs to be called regardless. Thanks - this was a huge time-saver!

Comment: For some reason that approach did not work for me in C# 4.0/4.5 - had to put curly braces after each `using( )`.  Than no `.FlushFinalBlock( )` call is needed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809687/#29835039.

Comment: @Astrogator: When execution passes out of the `using` block the CryptoStream object's `Dispose` method is called, which eventually causes the`Close` method and then the `FlushFinalBlock` method to be called.