# objective c aes 128 encryption for .net aes

Tags: c#, objective-c, base64, aes

So I finally found something a little more understable in implementing a AES 128 encryption for a .Net Wcf Service with the same encryption. My problem with it now is that whenever it would try to decrypt the string it would have a step where it does a FromBase64String convert which will give me an error:

```
static public string DecryptString(string message, string key)
{
    string output = "";
    Rijndael aes = new RijndaelManaged();

    try
    {
        byte[] encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        byte[] cipherText = GetCipherText(encrypted);

        aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        aes.IV = GetIV(encrypted);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                    byte[] decrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is:

> **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

and it happens on the

```
cs.FlushFinalBlock();
```

This is the encryption that it produced for the message "heythere" and a key of "25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b"

> 0suql40BUGiDoFA4SdXJAA==

This is coming from my .Net encryption:

> unNWQfm9RaU/HgKlDNEmoXZaTzsuBoTNsA2UvDKZhc4=

PS For the iPhone encryption of AES 128, this is where I got the codes from:

> [AES interoperability between .Net and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538435/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/)

Comment: Where is the iPhone code? The question you reference does not have it (the link in the question points to an empty page). One thing I noticed is that you are using the encrypted text as the IV; that's almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Also, AES is a "specialized" version of Rijndael. You need to make sure you set the correct key size and paddings (                 `KeySize = 256; BlockSize = 128; Mode = CipherMode.CBC; Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7`)

Comment: @gdubs: Your code might be astonishment to some people. Accomplish it at least in a correct braced block would be helpful in readability.

Comment: I don't see any Objective-C. Why is the question tagged as such?

Comment: The error is not reproducible. Please provide a correct minimum working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [AES Keeping your documents secure article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx) and scroll down to the section entitled "Using the AES Class", "Figure 15 Using AES" has a nice and simple example of encryption / decryption.

P.S. Be aware of padding that is used in certain block cypher (like AES) modes (like CBC), these can be a pain when different systems are talking to each other as padding / block sizes can vary from one system to another... see [padding fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545387/using-aes-encryption-in-net-cryptographicexception-saying-the-padding-is-inva)

EDIT: Just spotted this little gem... [simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a ready sample for both iPhone and .NET [here](http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2009/02/12/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/)

In general, cipher algorithm are universal and should work across different languages just you need to ensure that both algorithms (i.e. in .NET and iPhone):

- Using exactly the the same key that is encoded in the same way for storage/transmission (typically base64)
- Have exactly same parameters including padding schema, mode of operation (e.g. CBC/ECB)

Comment: that's actually what I tried to use to encrypt. decrypting is where i have some problems with since I did it differently from how he did it.